# Node JS connect over https Socks5 proxy timeout not work

Tags: https, proxy, timeout

I use in this code socksv5 module to get data over proxy server(Socks5) and https protocol.

But timeout parameter is not work.

```
var socks = require('socksv5');
var https = require('https');

var socksConfig = {    
    proxyHost: '127.0.0.1',
    proxyPort: 14452,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1',
    auths: [socks.auth.None()]
};  

     https.get({
            host: 'api.example.com',
            port: 443,
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/api-info',
            agent: new socks.HttpsAgent(socksConfig),
         timeout:1000
        },
        function (res) {
            res.resume();
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
            }).on('error', function (e) {
                console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            });

        });

    process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I want to change proxy if current proxy not respond after 10 seconds.